# See comments made on my comments?

Tags: support, comments

I know I can see all my comments via my profile --> Activity tab. But right now in order to see if someone else added a comment *(for example: OP asks a question, I ask for clarification in comment and then I want to see if he answered)* I have to go to each question separately and search for new comments made there.

My question is: do you have any faster way to see comments made on my comments, or added to questions I **commented** on?

Note, it's not relevant for answers, only when I added a comment without a full answer.

Comment: @abby no reason? [Sure about that](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/timey-wimey)?  ;) (thanks for the edit anyway, glad to see Winter Bash inspiring good actions :))

Comment: Is this similar to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251139/158100) feature request?

Comment: @rene no, this one here is when I don't know what question has the comments in the first place.

Comment: @rene if you can come with SEDE query that finds all comments posted on questions where I also commented (and after my own comment) I can accept it as the answer, since there's no real way these days to achieve what I asked here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can wait for 7 days you could use the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/409532?UserId=447356) and [this better performing one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/416371/see-comments-made-on-my-comments?UserId=447356) to achieve that:

```sql
declare @userid int = ##userid:int?447356## -- ShadowWizard
select c_orig.id as [Comment Link]
     , c_orig.postid as [Post Link]
     , (select top 1 id 
        from comments c_later 
        where c_later.postid = c_orig.postid
        and c_later.creationdate > c_orig.creationdate
        and c_later.userid <>  @userid
        order by creationdate 
        ) as [Comment Link]
from comments c_orig         
where
c_orig.userid = @userid
and exists (select top 1 1 
        from comments c_later 
        where c_later.postid = c_orig.postid
        and c_later.creationdate > c_orig.creationdate
        and c_later.userid <>  @userid
        )
order by c_orig.postid
```

The query finds if there exists ONE other comment after your last comment on a certain post. It lists your comment, the post and the comment after your comment.

There must be a full-table scan somewhere in this query because it takes awhile to run to completion.

Comment: Awesome, guess that unless the team add some new feature, this is the best we can hope for. :)

Comment: I might revisit this later to see if I can do something similar with the API @ShadowWizard

Comment: That would be even more awesome!

Answer (score 4):

There are two options:

If you want to track a question, just make it a favorite (click the star below the votes). You get notified if there is a change.

If you want to comment on a comment, use @username so the user gets notified.

Comment: Thanks, will try the Favorite way. :)

Comment: But what if we _don't_ want to favorite it because it's a new user question. Favoriting males it look like it's a good question. (Not implying all new userquestions are bad, but most are - even mine were)

Comment: @Cole "Favoriting males" - are you hinting something here? :-D

Comment: Sorry, but I have to unaccept this since for some years now (after removing the envelope) we are no longer notified in any way when new comments are posted on favorite questions.

Answer (score 3):

If somebody is commenting on your question or answer, you'll be automatically notified. Same goes if somebody is answering to one of your comments and pings you `@Shadow Wizard blablabla`.

Comment: Newbies (myself included) are not aware of the @user thing so I can't really count on this.... found what I was looking for though: mark the question as favorite, then all comments will appear under "favorites" tab of "Recent Activity" page of my profile: http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/447356?Tab=Favorites&StartDate=2010-10-28&EndDate=2010-10-28 guess that's the best I can hope for.. thanks for the help! :-)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: In that case I'd suggest that you accept the answer from Gamecat. ;)