# Visual Feedback that you have @-replied to someone properly in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications, comment-replies

Right now, when you respond to someone by using an @-replies, there's no visual indicator to let you know whether you've properly used the feature or not.

I'm often confused by whether I've used it properly or not - is it valid to have a : without a space right after their name? a -? Do I need to include punctuation that they have in their name? Is it valid to have multiple @-replies in a single comment?

Because it's not rendered in any particular way, it's impossible to tell whether it has been accepted as ordinary text or if a notification has actually been sent to the other user.

1. I'd like to request that it be rendered in a different style to indicate that it was registered.
2. Possibly the way it could be rendered is exactly like a hyperlink, and clicking on that link should then take you to their userpage.

I only have this special rendering in mind for after you've actually posted the message, but if it's possible to make it occur in the actual comment text box that would be cool, too.

Comment: What exactly is the @ feature called, anyways? I would have the name of the feature in my post, and I'd use the proper tag, if I knew what the name was. Is it "responses"? That tag has no accompanying wiki or summary to actually validate if it's the right tag or not.

Comment: *pinging* or *@-reply* I'd say @Art :)

Comment: I mean, if you pick an option from the autocomplete it's guaranteed to go to *someone* at least. Though there are a few additional candidates that the autocomplete [doesn't cover](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106534/expand-the-username-auto-completion-to-everyone-who-can-be-notified).

Comment: @TimStone - Yeah, but that box is only present while you're tying the name. The moment you type a -, or a :, or anything else, suddenly your visual indication that it worked is gone. Were those invalid characters that you typed, or was the visual indicator going to disappear anyways?

Comment: I have a comment-reply-highlighter-script [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251142/158100). That is not exactly what you request but it does do highlighting of comment threads for a user,

Comment: While it's a nice to have thing, I fear comments in general are not important enough to justify the required development time. When in doubt, just don't put anything after the `@-reply`.

Comment: The big issue with the hyperlink is that @comments don't change when a user changes their UN... so that could be really problematic over time, I would think...

Comment: My first reaction to this was "why not?"; but I think SE needs more than that to implement something.